# Página IIS Carregando Eternamente

Tags: webforms, iis

Tenho um aplicação desenvolvida em Web Forms rodando em um servidor IIS 7.5. De tempo em tempo, as páginas da aplicação ficam carregando eternamente, e para resolver esse problema rapidamente eu tenho que reciclar o pool de aplicação. Alguma pista de como solucionar/investigar esse problema?